# How to add a text field to the end of a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm implementing an entry field where users can enter tags. Once a tag is recognized, it is replaced by a UICollectionViewCell that makes the tag look prettier.

It looks something like this:

[image]

Now I would like to add the possibility to add another tag by just typing after the end of the current list of tags. Is there a way to do this? I was thinking of adding a cell with a `UITextField` in it or something similar, but that would create problems if I had to do line wrapping, since there might arise a situation where the user would've entered the first two tags on the picture above, and then I'd want a cursor to appear right after them. However, this would require adding a cell that would not be rectangular (if the user filled the entire first line, it'd have to wrap back to the beginning of the next line).

How is this usually done?

To clarify, if I added a text view to the end and the user entered something spanning multiple lines, it would probably wrap like this:

```
TAG1 TAG2 XXXXXX
          XXXXXX
          XXXXXX
          XXXXXX
```

Instead of wrapping like this:

```
TAG1 TAG2 XXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: so what you want is just have a different cell at the end of your collectionView that doesn't has an UIlabel with a tag  but an UITextField? I get what you want?

Comment: @MirkoCatalano: basically yes, but that won't work because of the line wrapping problem I described...

Comment: sorry but I don't understand really well your problem, what happen when the user add the first 2 tags?

Comment: @MirkoCatalano: see edit for a clarification, does that help?

Comment: ok now I understand you want something like your second example, but with a multiline textfield you actually have something like first example

Comment: @MirkoCatalano: yes exactly

Comment: you can have something like that in a collectionView, maybe you can have a cell with a width 100& your collectionView width and you can modify the height about your row in your text field, but no nothing more

Comment: you fix your problem?

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/aotag). There are other tag controls that might be suitable. Just browse this site, its quite resourceful and free.